# What is a general term for an organism with more than 4 legs?

Tags: single-word-requests

- A Unipedal organism has 1 leg
- A Bipedal organism has 2 legs
- A Quadrupedal organism has 4 legs
- A Hexapedal organism has 6 legs
- An Octopedal organism has 8 legs

But what is a general term that combines anything with more than 4 legs into one word?

Comment: I would edit your question to remove the specification that it be more than 4, because there won't be words that mean exactly more than 4, more than 6, etc., but, as you've been answered, there is a perfectly good general term for "many legs".

Comment: a drunk on all fours

Comment: Arthropod covers it pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myriapodous = having numerous legs.

This was a Crossword clue in today’s Age.

OED

> Origin: **Formed within English, by derivation.
>
> Etymology: < **Myriapoda** n. + -ous suffix.
>
> 1843   R. Owen Lect. Compar. Anat. Invertebr. Animals 201   *In the Myriapodous insects..the principle of irrelative repetition prevails in the nervous system.*
>
> 1998   Rec. Austral. Mus. 50 293   *The myriapodous arthropod Maldybulakia Tesakov & Alekseev, 1998, was first described from the Lower Devonian (Pragian–Emsian) in central Kazakhstan.*
>
> **Myriapoda**, n. **A group of arthropods comprising the centipedes, millipedes, pauropods, and symphylans, which have elongated bodies with numerous leg-bearing segments; (with plural agreement) such arthropods collectively.**

Answer (score 5):

**Polypod** is defined as having many legs. From [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/polypod):

> adjective
>
> Zoology
>
> Having many feet or similar appendages, especially denoting a phase of insect larval development characterized by a segmented abdomen with rudimentary or functional appendages.

The use does appear to have been extended to robots, where *polypedal* is also used.

Comment: The OP wants a word specifically for something with more than four legs. Polypod simply means many legs. Do you think this is specific enough to the request?

Comment: @Zebrafish, it's the best they're going to get. *Many* is ill-defined even with a little context, but I would say it excludes 4 here. Arguably it may exclude 6 and 8 as well.

Comment: See this question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437872/what-is-a-word-which-encapsulates-the-meaning-of-both-the-words-widow-and-fem/437876#437876  If I write an answer saying there's no such word for your request, should it be accepted and voted to the top?

Comment: @Zebrafish acceptance is up to the OP.  Votes are up to the individuals.  I wouldn't vote for "there is no word" in this case, because I've stated that there is one (even if not perfect), but I wouldn't vote down either.

Answer (score 1):

**multipedal**

There is no generic term for something with multiple legs that specifically excludes organisms with 2, 3 or 4 legs. You either have 0, 1, or more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Besides *polypod* that @Chris H suggested, there is also [*polyped*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/polyped) (as an adjective), which means having many feet. However, it doesn't actually specify having more than four feet. I guess it would depend on whether you consider *many* to mean more than four feet for your purposes. An organism with many feet can be called a *polyped* (noun).