# Adjective for "club that I am a member of"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for a good word to describe a club that one is a member of.

For instance, there might be five clubs, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`, two of which I am a member of - `A` and `B`.

I want say that `C`, `D` and `E` are *foreign* clubs, and `A` and `B` are ______ clubs.

None of the antonyms for "foreign" fill in the blank nicely. For example they are not "native clubs" or "domestic clubs"

What is a good word to describe a club that would convey that I am a member of it?

Comment: Not sure *foreign* is a good choice. Perhaps *current clubs* for your clubs that you’re a member of now?

Comment: That's an alright idea, but it sort of implies that I'm regularly changing clubs

Comment: The only thing I can think of is "my", although that also might suggest that you own or run the club, rather than just being a member.

Answer (score -1):

I have been a member of a particular club for nearly 50 years. I refer to that clubs  as 'my' club, and in the company of members of that club  I will speak of "the club", with the silent understanding that there is no other club worth speaking about.

I do not think there is a word for the clubs one does not belong to.

Edit: to clarify: my answer to "I am looking for a good word to describe a club that one is a member of" is: the only good word I know is 'my'. If that is not an adjective, then please read into my answer the additional point: there is no adjective with that meaning.

Whether there is a word for describing clubs one is not a member of was not formally part of the question, as I saw it, but was raised by the OP as an aside. And as an aside in my answer I noted that I did not think there was one.

Comment: Downvoted because you essentially answered "I'm not sure there is one". That should just be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @CodyBugstein - Actually his answer was ***my*** clubs.  You did not ask about words to replace *foreign* which was what his comment “I don’t think there is one” was about.

Comment: @Jim you're right, sorry. If Jeremy makes an edit on his answer, I can upvote

Comment: But my downvote is for a trivial answer (though I will justify it by saying that 'my' isn't an adjective).

Comment: @CodyBugstein For anyone thinking that an answer claiming there is no word or it's uncertain there is such a word to fill the request is a bad answer, refer to the top answer to this question https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/437872/what-is-a-word-which-encapsulates-the-meaning-of-both-the-words-widow-and-fem/437876#437876 I'm not claiming anything other than there's a chance there may be a double standard creeping in.